# powershell read lines on CSV as objects

Tags: powershell, csv

i need to create a powershell script that reads an CSV File with data separated by Semicolon, but the problems are that the firts line is the header, and i need to save all parse data except for the header as objects, right now i only have this to parse the doc

```
import-csv "filepath"  -delimiter ';'
```

Comment: The command you have here does exactly what you describe as what you want. Is there a problem with it?

Comment: it reapeats the header and i dont know how to put the values into variable, let me explain a little better 

csv FILE: 
col1;col2;col3
a;B;c
D;E;F 

what i want  

var1=a  var2=B var3=c 

what i get 

col1 a
col2 B
col3 c

Comment: right now what i got its a way to separate the data but i still dont get how to make them into variables 

$file = Import-CSV "filepath" -Delimiter ';'

$file | ForEach-Object {
        foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties) 
{         
$property.Value


}

    }

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found kind of a way, not in objects but array an thats works for me too, ill post it in case someelse need it

```
foreach($line in $csv){
    $nline = $line.Split(";")
    $nline[0]
    $nline[1])
    $nline[2])
    $nline[4])
}
```